# How can I change trace id in my lambda for xray?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

My lambda (Nodejs) is sitting behind `AWS Appsync` with xray enabled. When it receives a request from `Appsync`, there is a trace id in the context:

```
'x-amzn-trace-id': 'Root=1-5f4a4a2d-b94f96db34d41be1349080d2'
...
```

This ID is auto generated somewhere. Is there a way for me to use a different trace ID?
The event comes to my lambda has a `transactionId` and I'd like to use this ID as trace-id. How can I do that in lambda?

My use case for that is how to trace the event across dynamodb, latency application, event bus etc. For example, my `lambdaA` write an item to Dynamodb and there are 3 lambdas get triggered by the dynamodb stream. And these three lambdas process the event in a different way. One of them send the event to an latency system, one of them sends to event bus. I'd like to make them use the same trace id across the whole process.

I can follow the trace id requirement. My main question is how to pass it through different services, applications etc.

Comment: You're not supposed to change the trace id. It gets assigned by the first service processing an event, which has X-Ray enabled. Why would you want to change it anyway?

Comment: I have gave my use case in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function invocation generates a trace id and automatically creates a Segment for the lambda function. This segment is immutable. There is no way to change the traceid from outside the lambda function if you are not generating it from the start using an X-Ray SDK. From within the lambda function, mutating the trace id is not recommended as it may pollute the trace context. The AWS X-Ray trace id needs to follow [these requirements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-api-sendingdata.html#xray-api-traceids) to be accepted. Not sure if you decide to inject the `transactionId`, it would work.

Comment: I can follow the requirements for that. If I can't change the trace ID, can I persist it through difference services? I have gave my use case in the question.

Comment: X-Ray doesn't support trace id propagation on DDB streams yet, so you consumer lambdas will have disconnected trace. Unfortunately, there's no workaround for it. If you can somehow pass the `transactionId` through the DDB streams to the 3 lambdas, you can then set it as an annotation on lambda segment (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-segment.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-segment-annotations). Then in the X-Ray console, you'll be able to search the traces with this annotation value.

Comment: put it in annotation doesn't really link the trace as partent-child relationship right?